# Spring RestController - Intercept method invocation

Tags: java, spring, aop, interceptor

I have a Spring `RestController` with an endpoint consuming JSON. It converts the JSON to an object, and validates the fields (using bean validation):

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = "application/json")
public ResponseEntity<?> myMethod(@Valid @RequestBody MyEntity e) {
   ...
}
```

I'd like to intercept the invocation of this method only after the conversion and validation has taken place to have access to `MyEntity` and possibly abort execution.

Using Spring interceptors, I can only intercept the request before it reaches the method - so I don't have access to the validated bean. I can use Spring AOP and add a pointcut, but is there a way of aborting the execution nicely – ideally without throwing an exception?

This functionality is outside of the business logic of this method, and is temporary – so I want to separate it.

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution is to create a bean proxy between the Spring's proxy object and an object of your original class. To do that you need:

1. Implement your own `BeanPostProcessor`.
2. Spring will call its `postProcessBeforeInitialization()` method right after it has instantiated an object of your class, but before wrapping and initialising it. In this method, identify which beans must be provided with your functionality. It's often done by means of your custom annotations on methods or classes.
3. Create your own proxy for the beans from step 2. You can use cglib or something more modern for that. Your proxy will make all the checks you need and then call the parent's method if everything is ok, or just silently return from the method if something is wrong.
4. Return your proxy from `postProcessBeforeInitialization()`, it will instruct Spring to use it instead of the original bean.

As the result, Spring will create proxy of your proxy, not of the original object. When a request arrives, Spring will do the validation and send it to your proxy. Your proxy will make all your custom checks and decide on whether to send it further to your original class or to return immediately.